# Trouble retrieving all images in a div/img/@src carousel - Scrapy

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I am trying to grab the contents of multiple img/@src tags that are surrounded by a div tag as follows:

```html
<div class="carousel large-pdp-image transition" style="transform: translateX(-100%);">
  <img src="//images.footballfanatics.com/FFImage/thumb.aspx?i=/productimages/_4032000/altimages/ff_4032371-22eb81b61e99dcaf02b8alt1_full.jpg&amp;w=900" alt="" class="carousel-image">
  <img src="//images.footballfanatics.com/FFImage/thumb.aspx?i=/productimages/_4032000/altimages/ff_4032371-22eb81b61e99dcaf02b8alt2_full.jpg&amp;w=900" alt="Dan Marino Miami Dolphins Autographed Riddell Throwback 80-96 Authentic Pro Helmet with Multiple Career Statistics Inscriptions" class="carousel-image current-image">
    
 </div>
```

And when I run the xpath command:

```html
response.xpath('//div[@class="carousel large-pdp-image transition"]/img/@src').getall()
```

I still only get the first img src url. I want to grab both of those img src urls. Looking for any guidance or advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your Xpath because of slashes, you are trying to scrape the first image.

Your Xpath

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="carousel large-pdp-image transition"]/img/@src').getall()
```

Edit:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="carousel large-pdp-image transition"]//img/@src').extract()
```

Double slash will let you scrape all of the src of img.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried that code adding in the '//img/@src' with extract() and I am still only able to grab the first image... Is there anything else I could try to download all of the srcs under the img and have the xpath return a list of images? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try double slash with getall

Comment: I tried both extract() and getall(), but it still only extracts the first image. So for getall() the array is just of the first image, it is not grabbing all of the img src in the carousel, just the first still

Comment: could you please share the website

Comment: https://www.fanaticsauthentic.com/mlb-authentic/jerseys-autographed/o-5676+d-74006653+fa-01+z-812-1128347476?_ref=m-TOPNAV , so if you click on 'Nolan Ryan White Houston Astros Autographed Nike Replica Jersey with ''HOF '99'' Inscription'. You can see there are 5 images in the carousel and I am trying to scrape all of those img src links. Thank you for the help!

Comment: could you please try this  `//*[contains(@class,'carousel-image')]/@src`

Comment: response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"carousel-image")]/@src').extract() and getall() still are only returning the first @src image.

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything else I can try to scrape the multiple @src links w/ scrapy, still stuck on resolving this. Thanks

Comment: The website images probably loading on js if so you have to use selenium instead of scrapy.

Comment: Really? Could that be the case even if every other tag I scrape and the first img @src is being scraped and downloaded successfully every time? It seems as if it's an issue with me improperly retrieving everything (not just the first) and get all of the 'img src' tags. But you think my best bet is to try and re-write the scraper in selenium?